# How to get the operating system's "Currently Executing Thread" handle (NOT the "Managed Thread ID") in .NET 6?

Tags: multithreading, cross-platform, .net-6.0

In .NET6 I want to retrieve the native handle (NOT the "Managed Thread ID") of the OS thread, on which the handle-retrieving function just runs, as a (possibly casted to) UInt32.

I found a solution for Windows (using the kernel's "GetCurrentWin32ThreadId"), but I want to have solutions also for Linux, MacOS and Android, assuming that the respective implicit OS' object models contain also "Thread Handles".

To avoid senseless reading time consuming tries to lead me on other paths: my question is very precise, please don't ask "why"s! And please avoid "you could try"s, because I don't have access to Linux-Computers, Macs, Smartphones, and don't want to bother others by intermediate tests and/or even "tries". I need concrete definitoric "code snippet" answers.

I need it 1. for debugging purposes, 2. for .NET-ManagedThreadPool monitoring (if it always works correctly), 3. cross-checking with the Visual Studio output (about finished threads) and 4. some other (also platform specific to be handled, native) functions/stuff (e.g. native thread coordination, cross-process).

My goal:
I want to deliver my program(s) [atm especially the "OpenSimulator"-software, including the server (Windows, Linux) as well as the user's viewer (Windows, Linux, MacOS, iOS)] with a target-platform-independent .NET6-".exe", and an OS-respective target-platform-specific .NET6-.dll as the respective implementation for certain interfaces, to bridge the yet current compatibility-gaps, something/somehow like MAUI tries to do, but generalized more complete on the logical (.NET6) layer.